# Using subscripts and superscripts in minted

Tags: minted, subscripts, superscripts

I am using the minted package for code highlighting in my thesis. My minted command looks like this:

```
\newminted[ps]{js}{frame=lines,style=manni,fontfamily=courier,linenos=true}
```

And I used it like this

```
\begin{listing}[H]
\caption{Syntax of function declaration}
    \begin{ps}
    // My code is here
    \end{ps}
\end{listing}
```

I would like to use subscripts and superscripts within the minted code (I use it also for psuedocode and grammar rules, that's why I want subscripts..)

I've tried this to set `mathescape` as described here [Subscript and superscript in lstlisting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102483/subscript-and-superscript-in-lstlisting) but `\lstset` gives me Undefined control sequence error (I guess I am not using listing package...?)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `listings` and `minted` are very different beasts.

Comment: @egreg updated my question to show that my minted is within a listing, but I guess its irrelevant

Comment: @Bobyandbob valid point, sorry, I wanted to keep the question short and avoid wall of text... my latex scaffolding is kind of long

Comment: @emanek Yes, it's not relevant, the `listing` environment is another thing, independent of the `listings` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\lstset` is for `listings`, which is very different from `minted`.

You can use `escapeinside`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[ps]{js}{
  frame=lines,
  style=manni,
  fontfamily=courier,
  linenos=true,
  escapeinside=@@,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ps}
... code@$_1$@ ... code@$^2$@ ... code@$_1^2$@ ...
\end{ps}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `@@` you can use a different character that's not used in the `ps` environments.

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks! Now, would it be possible for the subscripts to "inherit" the font style and color from the minted environment? My subscripts are long-ish words and the math-y cursive + monospace looks funny togehter...

Comment: @emanek You should be more detailed in your question. Please, add a “real world” minimal example of the code you intend to typeset.